gcp equivalent for $__range in grafana
I was trying to make a dynamic promql query in GCP metrics to get the difference between pod restart count based on the time selected from the time selector box(underlined in the image).

The logic is to obtain the restart count back in time and subtract it from restart count now:
sum by(pod_name) (
    kubernetes_io:container_restart_count
    -
    kubernetes_io:container_restart_count offset ${__interval}
)

I tried running these queries individually to validate them and both these queries
sum by(pod_name)(kubernetes_io:container_restart_count)

and
sum by(pod_name)(kubernetes_io:container_restart_count offset ${__interval})

gave the same output, for range selected to be last 1hr, but they shouldn't have cause the second query uses offset ${__interval} while the fist one doesn't.
But in grafana when I ran this using $__range value, the second query
sum by(pod_name)(pod_restart_count offset ${__range})

was able to give us pod restart count for 1hr back in time.
Any solutions/workarounds on how to get the same result in GCP using or without using ${__interval}?

${__interval} is a PromQL variable and is used to represent the time interval defined by the Metrics Explorer (in this case). However, your metric (pod_restart_count) is, I think, invalid. Is this a Prometheus metric being exported to Google Cloud Monitoring? If so, it would usually have a prometheus.googleapis.com prefix.

@DazWilkin The value pod_restart_count is symbolic and doesn't represent the actual metrics name. And coming back to the ${__interval} variable, its not representing the metrics explorers time interval. But when I replace it with an hardcoded value it does show the correct value, hence this question.

I'm unable to repro your issue. The behavior is correct for me. The PromQL values adjust when ${__interval__} is used to correctly reflect whatever time range is specified in the UI.

@DazWilkin I updated the question, I hope now you can see the problem. The selected range isn't helpful in GCP when using ${__interval}
